# CefSharp get html source and return it

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cefsharp

I am writing a small programm that uploads images to a server using Cefsharp in C#.

I am almost done but I am stuck with retrieving the html response after the upload and correctly return it in my SendFileWebBrowser function.

My code is this:

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    // ... Code that gets the Images from my directory ...

            for (int k = 0; k < itemImages.Length; k++)
                 {
                     string responseFromSendFile = SendFileWebBrowser(itemImages[k]);
                     JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(responseFromSendFile);
                     string imageUrl = (string)jObject.SelectToken("imageUrl");
                 }
}

public string SendFileWebBrowser(string filePath)
{

    // .... Code that fill more request Data ....
    
    request.PostData.AddData(bytes);

    frame.LoadRequest(request);

    string htmlReturnImageUploadResponse;

    chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadingStateChanged += (sender1, args) =>
    {
         if (args.IsLoading == false)
         {
              chromiumWebBrowser1.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
              {
                  htmlReturnImageUploadResponse = taskHtml.Result;
                  richTextBox1.AppendText(htmlReturnImageUploadResponse + "11111111");
              });
         }
    };

    richTextBox1.AppendText(htmlReturnImageUploadResponse+ "2222222");
            

    return htmlReturnImageUploadResponse;
}
```

After I run the code my richTextbox1 looks litke that:
"htmlReturnImageUploadResponse Source Code missing"2222222"htmlReturnImageUploadResponse-Source Code exists"11111111

But I need it the other way around so I can return the response from my LoadingStateChanged Code part.

I am not a C# dev and I program only as a hobby. This is more a basic async question I think. I hope you can help.

Comment: I dont know if I understand right but... You have to wait the load. If not 222222 will almost always before 111111. 111111 occurs when load finish, which is usually after the method returns.

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to wait for the loading to end and after that my SendFileWebBrowser function should return the html source. My question is here how exactly do I code this that it will work correctly? I am really clueless how that works.

Answer (score 0):

I won't do it this way, but this is a cluncky workaround

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // ... Code that gets the Images from my directory ...

    for (int k = 0; k < itemImages.Length; k++)
    {
        SendFileWebBrowser(itemImages[k]);
    }
}

public void SendFileWebBrowser(string filePath)
{

    // .... Code that fill more request Data ....

    request.PostData.AddData(bytes);

    frame.LoadRequest(request);

    chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadingStateChanged += LoadingChanged;

}

//this is a little bit smelly
private async void LoadingChanged(object sender, ...Eventargs args)
{
    if (!args.IsLoading)
    {
        var source = await chromiumWebBrowser1.GetSourceAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        //you'll have to check if you are in main thread or use dispatcher
        richTextBox1.AppendText(source + "11111111");
        richTextBox1.AppendText(source + "2222222");

        chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadingStateChanged -= LoadingChanged;

        DoWhateverYouNeedWithTheHtml(source);
    }
}

private void DoWhateverYouNeedWithTheHtml(string html)
{
    string responseFromSendFile = html;
    JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(responseFromSendFile);
    string imageUrl = (string)jObject.SelectToken("imageUrl");
    //all the code wrote in Click method in the loop should go here. Let the event fire the event-dependent things, don't wait for it.
}
```

I have so many questions about how do you create the `chromiumWebBrowser1`, which events are you listening, why not subscribe the loading event in the instantiation...

Why not create an async queue of loads when you click the button and fire and forget it until you *really* need the results?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to tell I am a complete beginner in this and most of my code is merged from other stackoverflow answers. My Tool was initally using the standard webbrowser plugin from visual Studio, where everything was a lot simpler to do then with Cefsharp. I have read your code and I am wondering now if this will somehow work in my case: I have multiple Images that i upload (for loop in button click function). After the for loop i need all the imageurls responses from all done requests finally concantenated in a string as GET-Parameters for doing another final single request.

Comment: If you are a beginner don't hesitate in read. Read. Read. Read. In this case, I recommend read about asynchronous code in .Net and `HttpClient`s. I think you don't need an "entire web browser" for do some loads to internet. Is a little bit overkill.

Comment: Thank you, my program was initially using httprequests, but I had to change it to a web browser because of recaptchas on that page. without a web browser i could not get behind it. I restructured my code now, but it is now only possible to upload a single image. I am totally stuck now on uploading multiple images and read the responses to make a final single reuqest.

Comment: @SergejoWizz I don't know what page are you using, neither the API it uses. I can't help you more without more info. If you are looking to upload a batch, and recieve one single request as answer, the web-page api must allow it, and again, that goes out of the scope of the question you made. Try to make a question in code-review or in the SO chat.